# Array in Array with "OR" Criteria

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I'm generating a userlist from Wordpress and I want to display users which have the role subscriber or editor:

```
$args = array(
    'role' => array('subscriber','editor'),
    'meta_key' => 'last_name',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'order' => 'ASC',
);
```

So with that code, the user must have both roles subscriber and editor. What do I need to change so that the role is an "OR" criteria?

Comment: To what function are you passing `$args`?

Comment: [In WordPress 4.4+](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/wp-user-query-role_in-and-similar-constructs-not-documented-anymore) you can use `role__in` with `WP_Query` instead of `role` to generate a query that translates to the SQL `IN` statement, which behaves like `OR`.

Comment: `meta_query = array(
'relation' => 'OR',
array('key' => 'mykey', 'value' => 'myValue', 'compare' => '=='),
array('key' => 'mykey', 'value' => 'myValue2', 'compare' => '==')
)` - https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Comment: role__in works perfectly